# Importar CSV Para MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou criando uma tabela no MySQL, nela vou importar diariamente vários arquivos CSV com nomes diferentes.

Quando importar preciso que o nome do arquivo vire uma coluna na tabela.

Teste1.csv:

```
111111;HONORIO;20
22222;PEDRO;30
```

Teste2.csv:

```
33333;ROBSON;10
44444;JOAO;05
```

Preciso que ao importar pro MySQL fique dessa forma:

```
Teste1;111111;HONORIO;20
Teste1;22222;PEDRO;30
Teste2;33333;ROBSON;10
Teste2;44444;JOAO;05
```

Comment: Você sabe como vai importar arquivos com nomes diferentes? Não acha que vale a pena criar uma macro no excel que lê o arquivo insere uma coluna com o nome do arquivo e renomeia o arquivo e dispara o comando no mysql?